# How to automatically pull a sentence containing word X in a given language?

Tags: database, web

For example let's I want a real world sentence that contains the word "chercher" in French. (Eventually, the word & the language will vary)

So I would like to create a method for automatically pulling a sentence in language X for word X.

Is there a way to pull this automatically from an online resource, if so, how? How does one go about doing this? Explain like I'm 5, please!

Comment: Please add the current programming language and current database you are using. There is a different way to get that information dependent on the technology choices you'll make.

Comment: @DavidLaberge Currently it's just a Beta I'm setting up. Target words are entered in a form on a website, get sent to a Google sheet and then emailed to the user after a set period. So the website is obviously HTML/java and the Google Sheet uses Scripts. I hope this clears it up somewhat.